# how to get the data collection from this json data using newtonsoft json.net in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

how to get the data section in a loop to get the id name and type from this json data format in c# json.net

```
{
   "reactions":{
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"201852446499743",
            "name":"Kalna@kalna",
            "type":"LIKE"
         },
         {
            "id":"178345282632225",
            "name":"Riya Modak",
            "type":"LOVE"
         }
      ],
      "paging":{
         "cursors":{
            "before":"TWpBeE9EVXlORFEyTkRrNU56UXpPakUwT0RFeE1UVXhOekE2TWpVME1EazJNVFl4TXc9PQZDZD",
            "after":"TVRBd01ERXpOekF5TmpJek56UXhPakUwT0RFeE1UVXhNems2TnpnNE5qUTRNRE0zT1RFek16RXkZD"
         }
      }
   },
   "id":"1402884576396518"
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried to accomplish this?

Comment: You'll need a c# model to match the json structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way is to [deserialize](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm) into the [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) class like so:

```
// Fetch your JSON
string json = // however you retrieve this JSON

// Use JSON.NET to deserialize into dynamic
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

// Loop through each "reaction"
foreach (var data in result.reactions.data)
{
    // Show ID (can get name and type also)
    Console.WriteLine(data.id.ToString());
}
```

Output:

> 201852446499743
>   178345282632225

Answer (score 1):

You just have to import the [`System.Web.Script.Serialization`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization(v=vs.110).aspx)-namespace. Then you can use the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to deserialize your JSON-string:

```
Dictionary<object, object> data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<object, object>>(yourJSONString);
```

This returns a Dictionary where you will find the key "data".